# onmouseover. keep class until hover another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

What can I do to keep class 'po' untill onmouseover another element from class "Oobj" ?

```
    <div class="Oobj" id="Oobj51"> 
    <div class="przed"  onmouseover="this.className='po'
     "onmouseout="this.className='przed'"/>sport
    </div>
    </div>
```

Sorry..Must've accidently delete html and css.. It was here. 
Edit: 
I want to keep class 'po' on each div untill I hover another one and so on..

HTML:

```
<div class="Oobj" id="Oobj51"> 
<div class="przed"  onmouseover="this.className='po'" 

onmouseout="this.className='po'"/>sport
</div></div>


<div class="Oobj" id="Oobj52">
<div class="przed"  onmouseover="this.className='po'" 

onmouseout="this.className='przed'"/>rozrywka
</div></div>

<div class="Oobj" id="Oobj53">
<div class="przed"  onmouseover="this.className='po'" 

onmouseout="this.className='przed'"/>kultura
</div></div>

<div class="Oobj" id="Oobj54">
<div class="przed"  onmouseover="this.className='po'" 

onmouseout="this.className='przed'"/>ogólne
</div></div>

<div class="Oobj" id="Oobj55">
<div class="przed"  onmouseover="this.className='po'" 

onmouseout="this.className='przed'"/>muzyka
</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.przed{
   width: 84px;
   height: 84px;
   background: #4b8eb5; 
   -moz-border-radius: 70px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 70px; 
   border-radius: 70px;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-size: 18px;
   color: #262626;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 84px;
   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;    
}

.po{
width: 84px;
   height: 84px;
   background: #262626; 
   -moz-border-radius: 70px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 70px; 
   border-radius: 70px;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-size: 18px;
   color: #cbe9eb;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 84px; 
   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
}
```

Comment: This is not enough! Explain more and show us your `html` code as well

Comment: Remove the `onmouseout` handler and add code to the `mouseover` which removes the class from all other elements before adding to the current.

Comment: you could do nothing on mouse out (for this element) and code the mouser over the element to add 'po' class to itself and remove all other classes from other elements.  Does it make sense?

Comment: "code to the mouseover which removes the class from all other elements"
Can you give an example. Not sure how to type it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with jQuery, I'll assume you're using the library.  The good news is this is not difficult!  First you need to remove the onmouseover/onmouseout from your tags, and then add this to your file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.przed').mouseenter(function() {
        // remove any existing 'po' classes and add the 'przed' class back
        $('.po').removeClass('po').addClass('przed');
        // for the element just hovered over, remove the 'przed' class and add 'po'
        $(this).removeClass('przed').addClass('po');
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sG7Dx/)

Comment: Added a fiddle demo, next time do add them

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Satpal, I'm new to this site.  I added one as a comment about the same time you added the edit to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable witch contains the current selected element
and as you hover another element remove the class from current , set current to the new element and add the class.

here is an example but it's not based on your code .. as prieviously it was not visible.

```
function select(e){
 if(e.target.parentNode==this){
  if(current){current.className=''}
  current=e.target;
  current.className='selected'
 }
}
var a=document.getElementById('Oobj51'),current;
a.addEventListener('mouseover',select,false);
```

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/aZtVg/1/

as you can see in the example there is no need for so many onmouseover,or even id's.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.przed').mouseover(function() {
        $( this ).addClass( "po" ).removeClass( "przed" );
    });

    $('.po').mouseout(function() {
        $( this ).addClass( "przed" ).removeClass( "po" );
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add some english to clarify your answer.